# curl: (35) error:140943E8:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:reason(1000)

Tags: linux

When I try to curl graph.facebook.com, I'm getting following error

- Trying 163.70.144.8:443...
- TCP_NODELAY set
- Connected to graph.facebook.com (163.70.144.8) port 443 (#0)
- ALPN, offering h2
- ALPN, offering http/1.1
- successfully set certificate verify locations:
- CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
- TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
- TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS alert, close notify (512):
- error:140943E8:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:reason(1000)
- Closing connection 0
  curl: (35) error:140943E8:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:reason(1000)

Can anyone suggest what is the issue here? SSL is properly configured.
I'm using ubuntu 20.04

Thank you

Checked SSL and TLS. SSL is properly configured. Server supports TLS 1.2, 1.3

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: It is a docker container.